# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /bijwerkvlucht_post.php on this server

Tags: php

I know this has been asked hundreds of times, however, I couldn't find how this specific error applied to many of the other examples.

I have many form fields on a PHP page and they update into my database just fine when I hit submit, until I use http://somewebsite.net in one of the fields.

The field I post my form, field `flightaware` is posted to bijwerkvlucht_post.php as  `flightaware='$flightaware'`.

I do not get the above error message when I test with plain text or remove the http:// . Thus deducing that it is an issue related to http:// in the wording.

How would I fix the code to resolve this particular issue?

The code on the post page:

```
 <?php
 $host="localhost"; // Host name 
 $username="xxxxx"; // Mysql username 
 $password="xxxxx"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="xxxxx"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="tbl_vluchtgegevens"; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 // update data in mysql database 
 $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET reisID='$reisID', vertrekdatum2='$vertrekdatum2', 
 vertrektijd='$vertrektijd', vertrektijdactueel='$vertrektijdactueel',    
 vertrekluchthaven='$vertrekluchthaven', aankomstdatum2='$aankomstdatum2', 
 aankomsttijd='$aankomsttijd', aankomstluchthaven='$aankomstluchthaven', 
 luchtvaartmaatschappij='$luchtvaartmaatschappij', toestel='$toestel', 
 inschrijvingnmr='$inschrijvingnmr', vluchttijd='$vluchttijd', 
 vluchttijddec='$vluchttijddec',reisklasse='$reisklasse', stoel='$stoel', prijs='$prijs', 
 vluchtnmr='$vluchtnmr', vluchttype='$vluchttype', upgrade='$upgrade', 
 boekingcode='$boekingcode', eticketnmr='$eticketnmr', farecode='$farecode', 
 flightaware='$flightaware', route='$route' WHERE gegevenID='$id'";

 $result=mysql_query($sql);

 // if successfully updated. 
 if($result){
 echo "Successful";
 echo "<BR>";

 }

 else {
 echo "ERROR";
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: We have no idea how to help you without first seeing the code you've written.

Comment: We also need to know what database engine you're using. I wonder if you are not escaping fields before concatenating them in a SQL string? (If in doubt about whether to post code with a question, the short answer is **always post code** - it'll save you from down/close votes).

Comment: (Hmm, that said, I wonder if this is just an file permissions issue, or an Apache restriction, given the error in your title? Try examining the output of `ls -l` in the affected vhost folder).

Comment: I have added the code. Sorry, I was out of the country in a place where I did not have good internet access to access my pages contents. I am back now and can continue to work on this.

Comment: Can you add code of the `$_POST` part? You need to escape every field you're inserting in the database. Please also use PDO since the code your using now is deprecated.

Comment: this is all of the code on that page. so perhaps that is part of my problem. I'm not sure what PDO is. I am only a very short time amateur in this coding language. What I am using is basically cut & paste from other sites. This alone does not help my cause.

Comment: @DaniëlCronk you're Dutch right? Maybe we can chat in the chat section so I can explain a bit more.

Comment: Hi Andre - OK that sounds great. I am not able to do this today but maybe tomorrow I will have a little more time. dankjewel.

Comment: @DaniëlCronk voeg me toe op Twitter @ andrewoons dat communiceert wat makkelijker ;)

Comment: this has been resolved. my host for server had made changes to their mod_security. They have made some changes on their end and now my scripts run again.